# Move "Add to Cart" form below product description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to move only add to cart form below products description. To explain better:

[image]

Found this function, but it moves this at top of product under description. So some part of function is not right. Can someone to help me?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'customizing_variable_products', 1 );
function customizing_variable_products() {
global $product;
if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
}
```

Comment: you want to display "ADD TO CARD" above "Choose an option"?

Comment: Yes like is shown in image. So after add to cart is moved bellow description, variation selector will goes on space on add to cart.

Comment: I dont get why would you want to do that. I am saying that thinking if I was buying something, before I add it to cart I would have the option to choose the size

Comment: I want to havee that look. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy / paste all the woocommerce templates into your current template folder.

This way, the woocommerce theming isn't gonna take it's own templating but will take the one you pasted instead.

Then, you'll just have to find, where, in the template files where is printed the options, and where is printed the add to cart button. You'll be then able to switch the code sa that it makes what you need.

[here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) is the doc about how overriding templates files.

Comment: This can be done via function. Making template changes in not a sollution.

Comment: Moving all woocoommerce teplates files is a bad idea.

Comment: I don't know why you say it's a bad idea... This is explained in the documentation so why would they explain something bad to do ? I've made quite few WooCoommerce for customers, and if you want to design well the pages, you don't have choice, otherwise each time you update woocommerce plugin you waste all your work in template....

Comment: Looks like `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` is control both elements Variation selector and add to cart. How to separate that elements?